# Can I usably run Photoshop in a Windows VM with this setup?

Tags: graphics, hardware, photoshop

I'm researching hardware in order to build a new PC and I'd like to run linux as my main OS and just run windows in a VM. Do you think it'll be fast enough to run photoshop in a windows VM or will I still have to dual boot? Are the graphics supported by Ubuntu (both the Radeon card and the integrated chipset)?

My current plan is [here as an amazon wish list](http://www.amazon.co.uk/registry/wishlist/1MO3SIJGYKD8Z).

In summary:

- **CPU** - Intel i5 2500k
- **MOBO** - Gigabyte Z68XP-UD3
- **Memory** - Corsair 16GB (4x4GB) 1600MHz
- **Graphics** - Asus 1GB Radeon HD 6850 PCI-E 2
- **SRT** - Nocti mSATA 60GB SSD (just for the caching, I have another drive for main HDD)

Cheers,
Matt

Comment: I use Photoshop and Lightroom in Windows XP VM using 10 year old MB and 2GB RAM Sempron +1800     Answer is YES

Answer (score 1):

Those specifications will be more then adequate for your expressed need. You could probably use an i3 and less ram (4-6 Gb) if money is tight.

My only concern would be with the ati card, you might check compatibility with that (or wait for someone with more ATI experience then I have to comment.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which version of Photoshop, WINE is also an option. I run CS2 on my i5-based Lenovo laptop with a pretty wimpy integrated graphics card and it runs quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it should work. As for any problem with graphics, there should be a check-box in Photoshop settings that allows you to enable/disable GPU acceleration. With GPU acceleration disabled, Photoshop should work without any problems.